# How can I use Sparx Enterprise Architect with Code First?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, enterprise-architect

We are currently using Entity Framework 6 (EF) Database First approach to generate and maintain our database model classes.

I was hoping to use Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA) to maintain a SQL Server 2012 EE database design, and then EF Database First to "Update Model from Database" to maintain the EF model classes.

Now that Microsoft has officially announced they will no longer maintain any EF design approach besides Code First, how can I work with Sparx EA to keep our Code First models up to date if I do some database redesign with EA? I know Sparx will go 2 way with the database itself, but that does not help with Code First after the first creation of the Code First model created from the database, as I can't keep importing the entire database into Code First or we would lose our Code First customizations.

Comment: That's probably a good question, but should be addressed to the tool provider's support service. What you can get here are only shallow opinions of some end-users and if you're lucky some 3rd party Model-Driven-Generation provider may advertise their solution

Comment: I agree with @xmojmr. Never heard of such support with EA. You could model your (MS I guess) SQL Server using EA, but EA is not really a database modeling system. You can do it but it's clumsy.

Comment: I did ask Sparx (I'm not yet a customer) and was told Entity Framework and Code First were totally irrelevant to Sparx Enterprise Architect but don't agree with that assessment. I'm hoping for some shallow opinions from someone actually using EA with Entity Framework. It makes sense to me that EA can be used with Database First, but then that is going away now...so I don't see much use for EA in the Code First scenario and would also love some verification on if that is true or not.

Comment: This blurb from their website sounds like db modeling to me - Entity-relationship modeling is an abstract and conceptual database modeling method, used to produce a schema or semantic data model of, for example, a relational database and its requirements, visualized in Entity-Relationship Diagrams (ERDs).
ERDs in Enterprise Architect assist you in building conceptual data models through to generating Data Definition Language (DDL) for the target DBMS.

Comment: To add my shallow opinion to the mass. I don't believe a ready made solution for your problem exists for Enterprise Architect. But EA is open enough to write your own transformation/add-in to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code First - UML - Modeling of database - visual view possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384420/code-first-uml-modeling-of-database-visual-view-possible)

Comment: @xmojmr - not even close to a duplicate and not at all what I am asking.

Comment: I have been down this path. Unfortunately, Code First works best if it it is the master repository of the logical structure. Similarly, Enterprise Architect works best if it is the master repository of the logical structure. After various version control problems, we ended up dropping the Code First step and generating everything from EA and using In-house tooling I'm afraid.

Comment: @Chris - thanks even if disappointing to hear. I've asked Sparx to reconsider and rather than gen poco classes to better decorate and maintain a set of Code First classes. Not holding my breath since they think EA is irrelevant to the Entity Framework development process even though they basically already what what they claim not to.

Comment: @Chris - I'm finally picking this up again full time now. Regarding your in-house tooling - are you using EF6 or EF7? If so are you using EA transforms or something to generate the Code First code? Thx.

Comment: @Dave - Bad timing I'm afraid mate, I am totally snowed under. The approach we ended up with was based on two decisions. Firstly, that the model would change over the course of the project and we wanted any downstream artifacts to track the changes. Secondly, we wanted to be able to choose which sort of artifacts we wished to trace.

Comment: @Dave - Part2. Last time I looked, admittedly a while ago, the CF/EF approach failed on both counts.
A typical use-case might be generating search screens for your technical platform. So now you want to tag attributes and references in your static model as to which ones are searchable. The two methods that spring to mind are to go down the CF approach and enrich with custom attributes and your own T4 templates.
The second approach is to treat Enterprise Architect as the centre of the universe, add Tag Values to the UML model and write your own EA templates.

Comment: @Dave - Part3. Basically, the real problem isn't generating code, it is regenerating code and respecting customisation.
If customisation is done in separate files (such as partial classes that I hate with a passion), then regeneration isn't too bad. Due to my bigotry, we ended up with templates that had custom code zones that were preserved across system regeneration.

Comment: @Chris - Part 1. All good points I agree with except I actually like partial classes though wish they would change the language to allow merging of Attributes for same type and name in both classes. I am getting ready to try both LLBLGen and DevArt Entity Developer both of which claim to support MF, DF, and will generate via templates edmx xml or Code First code.

Comment: @Chris - Part 2  This is something Sparx should do that I have been trying talking them into. MDA is useless in the end if you can't actually convert the PIM layer to the PSM layer including all the relationships and attributes and ideally behaviours. Doesn't help much to not transform the relationships down to actual usable EF Code First code or edmx xml.

Comment: @Chris - Part 3. And both claim to support MF and DF interchangeably back and forth so you get the best of all 3 EF designer worlds inlcuding CF templates which is what I thought/hoped the EF team would have done with the V7 Designer instead of dropping the Designer, MF, DF and doing a non-compatible rewrite rather than a rewrite including current API. I like designers for viewing and configuring complex relationships and showing to other folks.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried EA with EF and decided to go with pure EF Code First. It is a lot easier since EA just doesn't work with EF at all well. Thanks for the suggestions. Chris, if you will post as an answer will be glad to mark it as such. You were right...